# LATEX table with same lenght of line

Tags: tables

i use this code to draw a table however, the are two lines that are not at the same length with others, here the table and the code :

[image]

```
   \begin{table}
    \centering 
    \hline
    \textbf{Vector Auto regression of order 2} \\
    %\textbf{Y\_gap, exchange rate depreciation and Inflation}\\
        \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2.5cm}}

 \hline
  \textbf{Dependent Variable }&&\textbf{Y\_GAP}& & \\
    \hline
  R-squared     =& &    0.6667 & & \\
Q-statistic   =  && -0.0311 & & \\
Nobs   =  & &  47 && \\     
Nvars = && 7& & \\
Variable  &  lag   &      Coefficient &    t-statistic&    t-probability \\
Y\_GAP    & 1   &       0.416480  &       3.016271 &        0.004433  \\
Y\_GAP    & 2    &      0.386314   &      2.794974        & 0.007933  \\
MOV\_DEP2 & 1    &     -0.027756    &    -0.933225       &  0.356303  \\
MOV\_DEP2 & 2    &      0.020908    &     0.600472     &    0.551579  \\
MOV\_INF  & 1    &      0.121292     &    0.859526    &     0.395173   \\
MOV\_INF  & 2    &     -0.325410     &   -2.467055   &      0.018002  \\
constant  &       &       1.232501       &  1.936710   &      0.059867   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\textbf{Granger Causality Tests } \\
\hline
    \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}
    Variable  &        F-value &     Probability\\ 
Y\_GAP       &    24.147591    &     0.000000   \\
MOV\_DEP2    &     0.473689    &     0.626149   \\
MOV\_INF     &     4.725186    &     0.014382   \\
%\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Xhay should they have the same widths? You have two tabular environments, with different column specifications and different number of columns. What are you trying to obtain exactly?

Comment: Ok i see thanks, i thought there is a way to make the line describing the title of table at the same lenght

Comment: The title of the table should be either in the caption, or, if you don't want any caption, as the first row of the table.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have two (logical) tables within one `table` environment. That's fine -- just provide separate `\caption` instructions and `tabular` environments.

Furthermore, I would recommend that you place the first table's auxiliary information about the R-squared statistic, etc at the bottom of the tabular, not at the top. Do also make an effort to align the numerical data in the three right-hand columns on the respective decimal markers. In the code below, I use the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) to achieve this goal.

Off-topic: What useful purpose is served by showing six [6!] digits after the decimal markers for all numbers? Might three digits do just as well -- or even better?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip,
            font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[group-digits=false]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering 

\caption{Vector autoregression of order~2. Dep.\ variable: Y\_GAP}
\begin{tabular}{l c *{2}{S[table-format=-1.6]} S[table-format=1.6]}
\toprule
Variable & lag  & {Coefficient} &  {t-statistic} & {p-value} \\
\midrule
Y\_GAP    & 1 &     0.416480 &   3.016271 & 0.004433  \\
Y\_GAP    & 2 &     0.386314 &   2.794974 & 0.007933  \\
MOV\_DEP2 & 1 &    -0.027756 &  -0.933225 & 0.356303  \\
MOV\_DEP2 & 2 &     0.020908 &   0.600472 & 0.551579  \\
MOV\_INF  & 1 &     0.121292 &   0.859526 & 0.395173  \\
MOV\_INF  & 2 &    -0.325410 &  -2.467055 & 0.018002  \\
Constant  &   &     1.232501 &   1.936710 & 0.059867  \\
\addlinespace
%% Provide an inner or "nested" tabular environment for the aux. information
\multicolumn{5}{l}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=-1.4]@{}}
    R-squared & 0.6667 \\
    Q-statistic& -0.0311 \\
    Nobs       & {47} \\     
    Nvars     & {7} \\
  \end{tabular}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip
\caption{Granger Causality Tests}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.6]}
\toprule
Variable & {F-value} &  {Probability} \\ 
\midrule
Y\_GAP      &   24.147591   &    0.000000   \\
MOV\_DEP2   &    0.473689   &    0.626149   \\
MOV\_INF    &    4.725186   &    0.014382   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much... for the help... your code is more Professional and table are clear to interpret .. u are also  right  using 2 digits seems better

Comment: @haithem - I'm glad you like the idea of showing fewer than 6 digits after the decimal marker. :-) One of the (many!) neat things about the `siunitx` package is that one can let the package do the rounding and truncating -- no need to edit the table entries by hand. E.g., if you wanted to show just 3 digits after the decimal marker, you could add the options `round-mode=places` and `round-precision=3` to the `\sisetup` directive, and change, e.g., `S[table-format=1.6]` (cf the first `tabular` environment) to `S[table-format=1.3]`.